# Oracle SQL - Importing Dates from CSV (Excel Format)

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, to-date

Sorry for the noob question (I'm trying to practice SQL with some databases), but how can I convert the following Excel date formats to   **MM-DD-YYYY**?

The original Excel column is in American format 'MM-DD-YYYY' and it goes to SQL as VARCHAR2:

[image]

So, as far as I know, I need to convert it to a number and then use **'TO_DATE()'** function (just got the first 50 rows to test):

```
     SELECT TO_DATE(TO_NUMBER(DATE1), 'MM-DD-YYYY')  FROM (
         SELECT * FROM CHEMICALS2 FETCH FIRST 50 ROWS ONLY
     )
```

and got the error **'01843.0000 - Not a valid month'**

[image]

I also tried to add 41293, after converting to number but got the same error.

Do you have a better idea to format that instead of changing the original csv file?

Comment: Stop. Alter your table. Change the column data type to DATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing TO_NUMBER function.

An example,

```
SELECT TO_DATE(DATE1, 'MM-DD-YYYY')  FROM (
    SELECT '10-18-2018' as date1 from dual
);
```

--UPDATE 
--Important note: 37894 it's the number from the excel cell

```
select (to_date('01011900','DDMMYYYY')-2)+37894 from dual;
```

Please: check if returns the correct date.

Good luck

Comment: got the same `ORA-01843: not a valid month` error. The dates to be transformed are in Excel's format, such as `43070`, `43344`, `43282`, but even applying some transforming functions (in other forums), I got the same problem...

Comment: mmm... Ok, according with the next link https://community.oracle.com/thread/205184?start=0&tstart=0 the excel date number is an internal representation. I've modified my answer to put their recommendation.
Please, let me know if it works fine

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much! I put the following: `SELECT (to_date('01011900','DDMMYYYY')-1) + A.DATE1 AS "DATE2" FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT DATE1 FROM CHEMICALS2 FETCH FIRST 50 ROWS ONLY
  ) A`